# Unable to override Magento Adminhtml Block

Tags: blocks, magento-1, adminhtml

I've been going around in circles here trying to find reason why my block is not loading when i extend it. Can you help me to extend it
Original file is

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Options.php
```

my file

```
app/code/local/Comp/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Options.php
```

comp_module/app/code/local/Comp/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Comp_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Comp_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <module>
                <class>Comp_Module_Block</class>
            </module>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>Comp_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options</catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Comp_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Comp_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Comp_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Please add more details about what error are you facing? also check your log files for errors.

Comment: i got this error: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Comp_Module_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options' in /var/www/project/web/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/project/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/project/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/catal...', Array)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and Mark it as correct so it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Update your 
**app\code\local\Comp\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Options.php** file with below code.

```
<?php
class Comp_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options
{

}
```

Re-compile if you have compilation enabled.

Refresh your cache.

Comment: Hey Jaimin, i managed to fix the issue by following your advice of checking the error logs. thanks!